# finding "almost" duplicates indices in a data table and calculate the delta

Tags: r

i have a smallish (2k) data set that contains questionnaire answers filled out by students there were sampled twice a year.  not all the students that were present for the first wave were there for the second wave and vice versa.  for each student, a unique id was created that consisted of the school code, the class code, the student number and the wave as a decimal point. for example 100612.1 is a student from school 10, grade 6, 12 on the names list and this was the first wave. the idea behind the decimal point was a way to identify the same student again in the data set (the only value which differs less than abs(1) from a given id is the same student on the other wave).at least that was the idea.

i was thinking of a script that would do the following:
- find the rows who's unique id is less than abs(1) from one another
- for those rows, generate a new row (in a new table) that consists of the student id and the delta of the measured variables( i.e value in the wave 2 - value in wave 1).

i a new to R but i have a tiny bit of background in other OOP.  i thought about creating a for loop that runs from 1 to length(df) and just looks for it's "brother". my gut feeling tells me that this not the way things are done in R.  any ideas?
 all i need is a quick way of sifting through the data looking for the second wave row. i think the rest should be straight forward from there.

thank you for helping

PS. since this is my first post here i apologize beforehand for any wrongdoings in this post... :)

Comment: chop off the decimal and calculate summary statistics (ie, delta) by the remaining id (100612)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question alludes to `data.table`, so here is a way to adapt @jed's answer using that package.

```
ids <- c(100612.1,100612.2,100613.1,100613.2,110714.1,201802.2)
answers <- c(5,4,3,4,1,0)
```

Example data as before, now instead of `data.frame` and `tapply` you can do this:

```
library(data.table)

surveyDT <- data.table(ids, answers)

surveyDT[, `:=` (child = substr(ids, 1, 6), wave = substr(ids, 8, 8))] # split ID's
# note multiple assign-by-reference := syntax above
setkey(surveyDT, child, wave)  # order data

# calculate delta on keyed data, grouping by child
surveyDT[, delta := diff(answers), by = child] 

unique(surveyDT[, delta, by = child]) # list results
    child delta
1: 100612    -1
2: 100613     1
3: 110714    NA
4: 201802    NA
```

To remove rows with NA values for delta:

```
unique(surveyDT[, .SD[(!is.na(delta))], by = child])
    child      ids answers wave delta
1: 100612 100612.1       5    1    -1
2: 100613 100613.1       3    1     1
```

Use `.SDcols` to output only specific columns (in addition to the `by` columns), for example,

```
unique(surveyDT[, .SD[(!is.na(delta))], by = child, .SDcols = 'delta'])
    child delta
1: 100612    -1
2: 100613     1
```

It took me some time to get acquainted with `data.table` syntax, but now I find it more intuitive, and it's fast for big data.

Comment: thanks! a quick follow up questions, if you don't mind:
- there is no need for the substr since i can create the child ID without using the wave. am i correct?
- if i have to subtract multiple columns can i calculate everything at once?  surveyDT[, delta1 := diff(answers), delta2:= diff(answers2), by = child] something along those lines?
- is there a way to filter out the results that didn't had two waves? i was thinking about using complete.cases..
again, thank you!!

Comment: if you post an example of your data set in your question, these type of questions will be a lot easier to answer.

Comment: `complete.cases` could work here, but note it removes rows with NA in any column. See edited answer for a way to filter NA's from specific columns. Re: multiple column calculations, follow how I used `:=` with backticks to assign child and wave in the example. See `help(':=')` for more.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that come to mind.  The easiest is to use the function floor(), which returns the integer For example:

```
floor(100612.1)
#[1] 100612

floor(9.9)
#[1] 9
```

Alternatively, you could write a fairly simple regex expression to get rid of the decimal place too.  Then you can use unique() to find the rows that are or are not duplicated entries.

Answer (score 0):

Lets make some fake data so we can see our problem easily:

```
ids <- c(100612.1,100612.2,100613.1,100613.2,110714.1,201802.2)
answers <- c(5,4,3,4,1,0)
survey <- data.frame(ids,answers)
```

Now lets split our ids into two different columns:

```
survey$child_id <- substr(survey$ids,1,6) 
survey$wave_id  <- substr(survey$ids,8,8)
```

Then we'll order by child and wave, and compute differences based on child:

```
survey[order(survey$child_id, survey$wave_id),]
survey$delta <- unlist(tapply(survey$answers, survey$child_id, function(x) c(NA,diff(x))))
```

Output:

```
       ids answers child_id wave_id delta
1 100612.1       5   100612       1    NA
2 100612.2       4   100612       2    -1
3 100613.1       3   100613       1    NA
4 100613.2       4   100613       2     1
5 110714.1       1   110714       1    NA
6 201802.2       0   201802       2    NA
```

Comment: thank you!
i ran the code in R to follow along.  the unique id mentioned was created from existing variables in the data. i.e i have a "wave" variable.  now that i see your suggestion, wouldn't a key set to "child, wave" would do the same? also, the last of your code is a bit fuzzy to me...
again, thank you for the quick replay! those are great ideas.

Comment: @isomitzi all I'm doing in the last bit of code is... 
if a kid has an answer in both waves, I subtract the score in the first wave from the score in the second wave. so child 100612 had a 5 in wave 1 and a 4 in wave 2, so his delta is -1.